# ComboBox в Delphi

Tags: delphi, алгоритм

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
i: byte;
sim : integer;
begin
sim := 0;
for i:=2 to 10 do
sim := ComboBox1.Items.Add(' Систему : '+IntToStr(i));
ShowMessage (intToStr (sim));
end;

end.
```

Мне нужно, чтобы ShowMessage показывал значение выбранной в ComboBox1. Сейчас он           показывает какие-то непонятные значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ShowMessage(ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так правильно:

```
ShowMessage(IntToStr(ComboBox1.ItemIndex)+' '+ComboBox1.Text);
```